# Update the parent table count updating a record in child table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

- **Departments** *(deptid(primarykey), deptname,empcount)*
- **EmployeeInfo** *(empid(primarykey),name, deptid(foreign_key)references deptid)*

When I update `deptid` of a record in `EmployeeInfo`, Immediately can the count be modified to accommodate the corresponding change.

An update  in child table will result in Increment and decrement in parent table.
I'm aware this can be done with a trigger, but is there a way using a stored procedure

Comment: Of course there is. What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: @Ghost I am trying to save the deptid before updating and then decrement the count, after updating Increment the count again. This is way tedious

Comment: Why do you need to persist `empcount` anyway? Can't you just create a view to return this information? `select d.deptid, d.deptname, count(*) empcount from Departments d inner join EmployeeInfo e on d.deptid = e.deptid`. This information will always be right without having to write any code in stored procedures or triggers. Also, the stored procedure can not run automatically on update of child table - that's what the trigger does. The only way for the `empcount` update to happen automatically is to also do the `EmployeeInfo` update in the stored procedure rather than in the table directly.

Comment: @Skippy   I want to update EmployeeInfo in storedprocedure only, update the corresponding count too in the same storedprocedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateDeptId(
@p_Employee_id int,
@p_NewDept_id int 
)
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE EmployeeInfo SET deptid = @p_NewDept_id
WHERE empid = @p_Employee_id

UPDATE T1  SET T1.EmpCount = T2.CountEmp
FROM Departments AS T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT deptid , Count(*) as CountEmp FROM EmployeeInfo GROUP BY deptid) AS T2
ON T1.deptid = T2.deptid

END
```

*Side Note: it is not best practice to store an aggregate value i a column, try using views or just run a query to retrieve it when needed*

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, an aggregate value should ***not*** be a static column that needs updating.

A view would be better.  That gets the count on-demand.

But if you insist...here is an option....that doesn't require nsync-ness with a stored procedure.

```
-- START TSQL

SET NOCOUNT ON


IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Employee' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
END 
GO


IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Department' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
END 
GO


DROP FUNCTION dbo.udfEmployeeCountByDepartment
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MyTinyInt] tinyint not null
    )


ALTER TABLE dbo.[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Department PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([DepartmentUUID]) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DepartmentName_Unique UNIQUE ([DepartmentName]) 
GO






CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ( 

    [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeUUID) 
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfEmployeeCountByDepartment(@DepartmentUUID uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnCount int
    select @returnCount = count(*) from dbo.Employee e where e.ParentDepartmentUUID = @DepartmentUUID
    RETURN @returnCount
END

GO



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD [ComputedEmployeeCount] as (dbo.udfEmployeeCountByDepartment(DepartmentUUID))

GO



Select * from dbo.Department

INSERT [dbo].[Department] ( DepartmentUUID , DepartmentName , CreateDate )
Select NEWID() , 'DepartmentOne', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL Select NEWID() , 'DepartmentTwo', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL Select NEWID() , 'DepartmentThree', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL Select NEWID() , 'DepartmentFour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP



INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] ( 
    [EmployeeUUID] ,
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] ,
    [SSN] ,
    [LastName] ,
    [FirstName] ,
    [CreateDate],
    [HireDate] 
    )
SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '111-11-1111', 'OneLN', 'OneFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '222-22-2222', 'TwoLN', 'TwoFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '333-33-3333', 'ThreeLN', 'ThreeFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '444-44-4444', 'FourLN', 'FourFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '555-55-5555', 'FiveLN', 'FiveFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '666-66-6666', 'SixLN', 'SixFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '777-77-7777', 'SevenLN', 'SevenFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '888-88-8888', 'EightLN', 'EightFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL SELECT NEWID() , (select top 1 DepartmentUUID from dbo.Department order by newid()), '999-99-9999', 'NineLN', 'NineFN',  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


Select * from dbo.Department
```